# How to disable/enable local notification in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

In my application, I'm saving certain coordinates and make them a geofence, so every time a user location entered a certain geofence, I will just put in the didEnterRegion delegate method some code that will notify the user that he/she entered a certain geofence. I'm using UILocalNotification in informing the user for that matter.

My concern is, In my Applications "Settings" view. I have a toggle button there for enabling/disabling Notification. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: store boolean value in nsuserdefault, and if is yes scheduled local notification otherwise no

Answer (score 3):

There is no any particular property for enable/disable of `UILocalNotification` so we can't easily handle it. For do enable and disable `UILocalNotification` (In your case),

I just put my logic

```
if(toggleButtonEnable)
{
  // First remove all LocalNotifications with set it's BadgeNumber = 0 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

  // Then write code of UILocalNotification with it's fireDate
}
else
{
   // remove all LocalNotifications with set it's BadgeNumber = 0
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

By use of above code, whenever `if condition` is become **true** then first remove/cancel all notification and set **badge = 0;** and create new `UILocalNotification` and when `if condition` is become **false** then also remove/cancel all notification and set **badge = 0;**. So you can easily handle *(enable/disable)* `UILocalNotification`.

Comment: in my case i want to off LocalNotification for Particular UserId. i have so many list of the users. plz help me..

Answer (score -5):

There is no way to enable/disable the local notifications. But there is one way to do this one.

remove the notification (disable the notification)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"NotifyName" object:nil];
```

after that add notification (enable the notification)

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(abc:) name:@"NotifyName" object:nil];
```

Comment: Local notifications are not `NSNotification`s